# How to find multiple Pattern(s) (using Matcher) in Java

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a `String`, say `one two three one one two one`.
Now I'm using a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` to find any specific `Pattern` in the `String`.
Like this:

```
Pattern findMyPattern = Pattern.compile("one");
Matcher foundAMatch = findMyPattern.matcher(myString);
while(foundAMatch.find())
           // do my stuff
```

But, suppose I want to find multiple patterns. For the example `String` I took, I want to find both `one` and `two`. Now it's a quite small String,so probable solution is using another `Pattern` and find my matches. But, this is just a small example. Is there an efficient way to do it, instead of just trying it out in a loop over all the set of `Pattern`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the power of regular expressions: change the pattern to match `one` or `two`.

```
Pattern findMyPattern = Pattern.compile("one|two");
Matcher foundAMatch = findMyPattern.matcher(myString);
while(foundAMatch.find())
           // do my stuff
```

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question,that it is just a small example. What if I have many,say about 100 plus,patterns to match for?

Comment: Just create the string one|two|three.. dynamically using a loop

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you're trying to do. If the patterns still look like they do in your example, you don't need a pattern at all. You can use `String#contains()`. Or do what Amit suggests.

Answer (score 0):

this wont solve my issue, this way we can change (one|two) to a perticular string.

but my requirementis to change 
pattern one -> three & two -> four