# Avoid repeat for writing regex in java for match keywords for multiple pattern?

Tags: java, regex, refactoring

I have N keywords, `key1` `key2` ... `keyN`.

I have 3 pattern to match the keywords. (To make the problem simple I just use `key1` instead of real keyword)

`/keyword` `{keyword}` `(keyword)`

I decide to find the match pattern by simply using regex:

The pattern I wrote:

```
(?:/)(key1|key2|key3)|(?:{)(key1|key2|key3)(?:})|(?:\()(key1|key2|key3)(?:\))
```

But for the keyword(`key1|key2|key3`), I need to write 3 times, also I got 3 groups (should be reduce to 1 for the best result).

How can I achieve this in Java or the standard regular expression ?

Comment: Use string concatenation to build your regex. There is no better way in Java regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Regex Multiple Pattern Group Replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815523/java-regex-multiple-pattern-group-replace)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723277/how-to-find-multiple-patterns-using-matcher-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (if I didn't miss any edge cases), but might be a bit cumbersome.

You can try this regex:

```
"([{/(])(aaa|bbb|ccc)((?<=/(aaa|bbb|ccc))|(?<=\\((aaa|bbb|ccc))\\)|(?<=\\{(aaa|bbb|ccc))\\})"
```

- `([{/(])` matches `/`, `(`, `{`
- `(aaa|bbb|ccc)` matches your key (group 2)
- `(?<=/(aaa|bbb|ccc))` matches nothing, but has a lookbehind that makes sure that `/` is at the beginning

  - `(?<=\\((aaa|bbb|ccc))\\)` matches `)` and with the lookbehind makes sure that  `(` is at the beginning
  - `(?<=\\{(aaa|bbb|ccc))\\}` matches `}` and with the lookbehind makes sure that  `{` is at the beginning

Using the information from this question: [Backreferences in lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734977/backreferences-in-lookbehind)
you can try this regex without repitions:

```
"([{/(])(aaa|bbb|ccc)((?<=(?=/\\2).{1,4})|(?<=(?=\\(\\2).{1,4})\\)|(?<=(?=\\{\\2).{1,4})\\})"
```

where `.{1,4}` should be as long as needed to match your keys

Comment: Your answer used the `key1|key2|key3` more than 3 times. I'll check your group trick

Comment: Well unfortunately it is not possible to use backreferences in lookbehinds (at least in Java regex), so I am afraid there is no way to avoid that repition. But the match is always in group 2, so at least there are no if statements or so neceassary to retrieve the result